# Simple term query not working with elastic while match works

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a JSON object like below in Elastic.

```
{
    "_source" : {
      "version" : 1,
      "object_id" : "f1dcae27-7a6f-4fea-b540-901c09b60a15",
      "object_name" : "testFileName_for_TestSweepAndPrune",
      "object_type" : "",
      "object_status" : "OBJ_DELETED",
      "u_attributes" : ""
    }
```

}

My term query like this doesn't work.

```
{
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "object_status": "OBJ_DELETED"
                }
            },
            "size": 10000
```

}

Wile match query works fine with same conditions.

```
{
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "object_status": "OBJ_DELETED"
                }
            },
            "size": 10000
```

}

Wondering what could be happening here? How can I make the term query work here for this condition?

Comment: Which analyzer do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by which analyzer? I have the stock elasticsearch installation with everything that comes along with default. I don't have mapping/schema for my data as well. Just a simple Json inserted and trying to query with on json.elem with term query

Comment: Try to run `{"object_status.keyword": "OBJ_DELETED"}` for term query and let me know if it works.

Comment: @rkm Yes. that worked!! I 'm still trying to understand the logic though

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To understand why `term` query is not working as you expect it we need to check how `ElasticSearch` process and saves data and how `match` and `term` queries are different.

Normally when you save some text into `ElasticSearch` it is analyzed first and then saved. Analysis is done by [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html). There are many analyzers, but if you don't specify any then default one will be used. Analyzer processes text, converts it into array of tokens and saves the list of tokens. The rules how text is splitted into tokens are different for each particular analyzer.

When text is processed and saved you can query it. There are many ways to query something, but in your case the main difference between `match` and `term` is that `match` is [full text query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html) and `term` is [term level query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html). The thing is that in case of full text search your query string is analyzed in the same way as the field you are querying was analyzed. In term level queries query string is not analyzed. It's important to note.

Now let's see how `"OBJ_DELETED"` is analyzed by `ElasticSearch`. For that we can add simple document like this:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/testdata/object/1' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "object_status": "OBJ_DELETED"  }'
```

Then check that everything is there:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/testdata/_search?pretty'
```

should produce something like this:

```
...
"hits" : {
"total" : 1,
"max_score" : 1.0,
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "testdata",
    "_type" : "object",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "object_status" : "OBJ_DELETED"
    }
  }
]
```

}

Now we can check how `"OBJ_DELETED"` is analyzed:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/testdata/_analyze?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "text": "OBJ_DELETED"  }'
```

and it outputs:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "obj_deleted",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see it only converted text into lowercase and saved it as one token. This is how default analyzer does it. Now returning to your queries. `match` query works because query value `"OBJ_DELETED"` is also converted to lowercase under the hood and thus `ElasticSearch` can find it. And for `term` query the query string is not processed so actually you are comparing `OBJ_DELETED` with `obj_deleted` and obviously you get no results.

And last question: why `object_status.keyword` works for `term` query?

By default `ElasticSearch` create additional mapping for each text field. It's kind of metadata that you can use. Also it allows you to process the same value in different ways. So by default each [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) field has additional mapping with name `keyword` which has type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html). `keyword` fields are not analyzed (they only can be normalyzed if needed). It means that for default mapping it saves the exact value that you passes to `ElasticSearch` (`OBJ_DELETED` in your case).

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using the `term` query for `text` fields (see [term query notes in guidelines](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-query-notes)). By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields during analysis. For example, the default [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) changes text field values as follows:

- Removes most punctuation
- Divides the remaining content into individual words, called [tokens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html)
- Lowercases the tokens

You can use [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) to produce the correct and searchable `term` from appropriate field in your index. Elasticsearch offers a variety of ways to [specify analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/specify-analyzer.html).