# How can I use a Term Query to search within this array?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index where certain properties of my document can be array-valued IDs, i.e.

```
POST temp/_doc
{
  "test": ["5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho68","5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho69"]
}
```

Now, when I want to search documents containing a certain ID, a [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) like this one:

```
POST temp/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "test": "5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho68"
    }
  }
}
```

gives no results. If I try it with simpler values (e.g. "foo" and "bar" instead of the IDs), it works. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple term query not working with elastic while match works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412359/simple-term-query-not-working-with-elastic-while-match-works)

Comment: @IanGabes perhaps - fundamentally it might be the same problem, except that I could isolate this case to arrays (and 'complicated' strings) which aren't mentioned there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, instructing Elasticsearch to use the keyword part of the field works:

```
POST temp/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "test.keyword": "5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho68"
    }
  }
}
```

gives one hit.

I could have avoided this situation by specifying the mapping upfront like this, instead of letting Elasticsearch guess it based on the document I posted; by default, it will use a text field instead of a keyword.

```
POST temp/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "test": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add to your answer that there's no 'complexity' distinction between the string `hey` and `5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho68` -- they get analyzed equally.

As to the array aspect which may be confusing at first -- there is [no dedicated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html#array) `array` data type in ES. You should define the mapping for the array values as strings (or keywords).

Side note: it's recommended not to intermix different types in one particular array -- but you're good to go w/ `["5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho68", "5T8QLHIBB_kDC9Ugho69"]`